# wordperss contact form 7 doesn't send html content

Tags: php, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

i'm pretty new to wordpress and contact form, so i've installed wp 
and contact form 7 and then, i installed ckeditor to make it more nice for the user.
Then, i created a new form with this code:

```
<p>השם שלך (חובה)<br />
[text* name placeholder "השם שלך"] </p>

<p>האימייל שלך: (חובה)<br />
[email* email placeholder "האימייל שלך"] </p>

<p class="block">נושא<br />
[text subject placeholder "נושא ההודעה"] </p>

<p class="block message">ההודעה שלך<br />
[textarea message class:ckeditor placeholder "תוכן ההודעה"] </p>

<p class="block submit-wrapper text-left">[submit "שלח"]</p>
```

And those in settings i checked the option "use html content".
When i sent the email from the site (on the local, using xampp) and the enail was sent but the [textarea message] wasn't there.
After that, i unchecked the "use html content" and sent the email again.
The message was there but it was a plain text, the html tags were escaped.

Any help? thanks :)

Comment: Show me your html email code .. So, that i can figure out better.

Answer (score 3):

Download the latest Contact form 7 from :`https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/`
if below option not there in contact form 7
[image]

change high lighted setting As per screenshot. This work for you..

Comment: it doesn't work for me, this is exactly what i did. It sends the email and the html content that in the "Message Body", but doesn't send the content from the textarea

Comment: you need to setup smtp to send mail locally bro!! This plugin help you bro : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Comment: i already did it, and as i said, the email was sent, but doesn't send the html from the ckeditor

Comment: ok so there must be problem with you html content and fields so please check you all fields related to send mail!

Comment: just checked, every thing there is ok,
its sends the html but the message from the user, became like that (example): <b>bold text</b> and not like that: **bold text**

Comment: if you have successfully check all information above. please replace plugin with new code and do proper check. i think some file may be changed by you on plugin.

Comment: which new code? that you provided up there?
and if you ask, i didn't change the code

Comment: download the plugin again and place fresh code. may be help you!

Comment: hello style shit you told me that when i check the "use html content" the textarea value  not appearing so i recommend you to  add <b>[message]</b> into your message body text and keep  "use html content" checked. i hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

`HTML` content is not allowed in `contact form 7` for security reason.

Read this [reference](https://contactform7.com/2016/01/27/html-is-not-allowed-in-messages/)